# How get an RGB Bitmap by using ByteBuffer (no color correction)?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-mediacodec, bytebuffer, decoder

I have an mp4 video in my sd card

```
MediaFormat = {
               repeat-previous-frame-after=66666,
               mime=video/avc,
               frame-rate=15,
               color-format=2130708361,
               height=720,
               width=1280,
               bitrate=1000000,
               i-frame-interval=1
    }
```

If I set Surface in  MediaCodec.Decoder configure then image is created correctly.

If I don't and create Bitmap with ByteBuffer I get an incorrect color image.
I tried YuvImage, and method for converting YUV420 to RGB, and ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB  but can't get a correct bitmap;

I need to create a Bitmap and not setting surface in MediaCodec.Decoder.configure!

```
private class PlayerThread extends Thread {
    private MediaExtractor extractor;
    private MediaCodec decoder;
    private Surface surface;
    private boolean needStop = false;
    final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 10000;

    PlayerThread(Surface surface) {
        this.surface = surface;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            extractor.setDataSource(SAMPLE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < extractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
            MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
                extractor.selectTrack(i);
                try {
                    decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                decoder.configure(format, /*surface*/ null, null, 0);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (decoder == null) {
            return;
        }
        decoder.start();

        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean isEOS = false;
        while (!Thread.interrupted() && !needStop) {
            if (!isEOS) {
                int inIndex = -1;
                try {
                    inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (inIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
                    int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
                    if (sampleSize < 0) {
                        if (!needStop) {
                            decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                            isEOS = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            if (!needStop) {
                                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                                extractor.advance();
                            }
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            int outIndex = MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER;
            try {
                if (!needStop) {
                    outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            switch (outIndex) {
                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                    outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                    break;
                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                    break;
                case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                    break;
                default:
                    ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];

                    buffer.position(info.offset);
                    buffer.limit(info.offset + info.size);
                    byte[] ba = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                    buffer.get(ba);
                    //this i use many algorithm conversion for get bitmap

                    YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(ba, ImageFormat.NV21, 1280, 720, null);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, 1280, 720), 80, baos);
                    byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();
                    final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
                    if (bmp != null) {
                        srcRect.left = 0;
                        srcRect.top = 0;
                        srcRect.bottom = 720;
                        srcRect.right = 1280;
                        Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas(dstRect);
                        try {
                            if (canvas != null) {
                                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, srcRect, dstRect, null);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (canvas != null) {
                                surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "bmp = BAD");
                    }

                    while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() -
                            startMs && !needStop) {
                        try {
                            sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            PlayerThread.this.interrupt();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, false);
                    break;
            }

            if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        decoder.stop();
        decoder.release();
        extractor.release();
    }
}
```

How to correct the conversion ByteBuffer (decoder) in Bitmap?
[image: Auto decoder render in surface]

[image: No correct color bitmap]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. Now i don't use ByteBuffer and get with decoder Image and it help me in may problem

*Now need refactoring code and implement variables such as video Size, surface size in dynamic mode*

Corrected code

```
  private class PlayerThread extends Thread {
    private MediaExtractor extractor;
    private MediaCodec decoder;
    private Surface surface;
    private boolean needStop = false;
    final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 10000;


    PlayerThread(Surface surface) {
        this.surface = surface;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            extractor.setDataSource(SAMPLE); //path MP4 file
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < extractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
            MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
                extractor.selectTrack(i);
                try {
                    decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                decoder.configure(format, /*surface*/ null, null, 0);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (decoder == null) {
            return;
        }
        decoder.start();

        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean isEOS = false;
        while (!Thread.interrupted() && !needStop) {
            if (!isEOS) {
                int inIndex = -1;
                try {
                    inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (inIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
                    int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
                    if (sampleSize < 0) {
                        if (!needStop) {
                            decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                            isEOS = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            if (!needStop) {
                                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                                extractor.advance();
                            }
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            int outIndex = MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER;
            try {
                if (!needStop) {
                    outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            switch (outIndex) {
                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                    outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                    break;
                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                    break;
                case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                    break;
                default:
                    Image image = decoder.getOutputImage(outIndex);
                    Image.Plane[] plants = image.getPlanes();
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    if (plants != null && plants.length > 0) {
                        YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(YUV_420_888toNV21(image), ImageFormat.NV21, 1280, 720, null);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, 1280, 720), 80, baos);
                        byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
                    }

                    if (bmp != null) {
                        srcRect.left = 0;
                        srcRect.top = 0;
                        srcRect.bottom = 720;
                        srcRect.right = 1280;
                        Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas(dstRect);
                        try {
                            if (canvas != null) {
                                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, srcRect, dstRect /*0,0, surfaceChanged
                                dstRect.right = width;
        dstRect.bottom = height;*/,
                                        null);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (canvas != null) {
                                surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() -
                            startMs && !needStop) {
                        try {
                            sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            PlayerThread.this.interrupt();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, false);
                    break;
            }

            if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        decoder.stop();
        decoder.release();
        extractor.release();
    }

}
private static byte[] YUV_420_888toNV21(Image image) {
    byte[] nv21;
    ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer uBuffer = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer vBuffer = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
    int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();
    int uSize = uBuffer.remaining();
    int vSize = vBuffer.remaining();
    nv21 = new byte[ySize + uSize + vSize];
    //U and V are swapped
    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize);
    vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize);
    uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize);
    return nv21;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you in 2022! Example for Yuv to bitmap helped a lot in writing a mock test.

Comment: Although, I used MediaCodec.Callback() implementation like here to get the input/output buffers https://gist.github.com/buyoh/f9004ecbe9fd8c1becc60930315eb7fc